# How can I support multiple types of VR controllers at the same time in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality, webvr, webxr

I'm using [A-Frame](https://aframe.io) and I'm trying to figure out how to easily support multiple types of controllers at once (Oculus Touch, HTC Vive controllers, and Windows Mixed Reality controllers), preferably with controller models rendered in the scene and with lasers that would allow the user to click on things.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this, so here's my solution.

In your HTML, you can have these to create the controllers (this should be inside an `a-scene` element):

```html
<a-entity laser-controls="hand: left" raycaster="showLine: true; objects: .clickable;"></a-entity>
<a-entity laser-controls="hand: right" raycaster="showLine: true; objects: .clickable;"></a-entity>
```

These should also render with the actual controller models in the scene, and each have a laser pointer.

This is what it looks like with the Oculus Touch controllers (ignore the other stuff in the view):

[image: VR view with controllers rendered]

As new types of headsets come out and are supported by A-Frame (e.g. the Valve Index controllers aren't supported yet), the laser-controls component should automatically be updated to support them.

See [the docs](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/introduction/interactions-and-controllers.html) for a bit more information on how to use controllers in your A-Frame scene.

I still haven't figured out exactly how to make it possible to click on buttons or objects in the environment using the laser, I'll need to figure that out next.

Comment: Alternatively, if you need a laser pointer kind of controls you can use the [laser-controls component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/laser-controls.html#sidebar)